What blockchain provider to use with react native
I am building a mobile dapp using react native. I have used walletconnect's provider with this hook:
    const {open, isConnected, provider, address} = useWalletConnectModal();

and then I use the provider to create a walletClient with Viem:
const walletClient = createWalletClient({
      account,
      chain: sepolia,
      transport: custom(provider),
    });

But I have a problem when sending the transactions, it often says: the execution reverted for unknown reason. I think the problem is with provider. Can anyone help with a solution for this issue.
Thanks.
